# How to find elements by href value using selenium python?

Tags: python, selenium

Is there any way to pull links from href values and open them one by one, and perform an action (click) on a specific ID?

Comment: welcome to SO! please read [MCVE] and edit your post accordingly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, find element by ID

```
element = driver.find_element_by_id('YOUR_ID')
```

Second, get attribute from your element

```
link = element.get_attribute("href")
```

Third, use selenium, but I would suggest using something like requests, and perform GET request by this link:

```
import requests
response = requests.get(link)
assert response.status_code == 200
```

for example